# How to update data in a Google sheet depending upon another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to update a cell with a defined value automatically by comparing and referencing this data from another Google sheet.

In Sheet1 `Column_C` is to be updated by comparing `Column_A` in Sheet1 to `Column_A` in Sheet2.

If it is a match, and `Column_B`'s value from Sheet2 is 1, then the result should be "issued", otherwise it should be "in-stock".

Sharing google sheet link :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h_D5u16ye1CA6C7dideJVZoV8cBvZB8M3RRxXBANsf4/edit?usp=sharing

How can I accomplish this using Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in cell `C1` (delete all other values below):

```
=arrayformula({"Status";if(A2:A<>"",substitute(substitute(iferror(vlookup(A2:A,filter(sheet2!A:B,countifs(sheet2!A:A,sheet2!A:A,row(sheet2!A:A),">="&row(sheet2!A:A))=1),2,0),),1,"Issued"),0,"In-Stock"),)})
```

[image]

To handle items in sheet1 that are not in sheet2, you can add a value in the `iferror` function (the first `"In-Stock"` below):

```
=arrayformula({if(A2:A<>"",substitute(substitute(iferror(vlookup(A2:A,filter(sheet2!A:B,countifs(sheet2!A:A,sheet2!A:A,row(sheet2!A:A),">="&row(sheet2!A:A))=1),2,0),"In-Stock"),1,"Issued"),0,"In-Stock"),)})
```

This is responsible for getting the dataset from sheet2:

`filter(sheet2!A:B,countifs(sheet2!A:A,sheet2!A:A,row(sheet2!A:A),">="&row(sheet2!A:A))=1)`

This part gets the instance number of each duplicate value in `sheet2!A:A`:

`countifs(sheet2!A:A,sheet2!A:A,row(sheet2!A:A),">="&row(sheet2!A:A))`

Where there are duplicate values, `">="` gets the one furthest down the sheet. Changing it to `"<="` will get the first instance at the top of the sheet.

Within `filter`, `countifs(sheet2!A:A,sheet2!A:A,row(sheet2!A:A),">="&row(sheet2!A:A))=1)` filters the column to show just `1` instance of each value in `sheet2!A:A`.

Looking at your example sheet, you have these values in row 6, 7, 8, so the first instance (ascending or descending) will be `0`:

```
1230E   0
1230E   1
1230E   0
```

If you're looking for a different logic, like `1` trumps `0`, then you'll need to apply a sort on the data before performing the vlookup. Something like:

```
=arrayformula({if(A2:A<>"",substitute(substitute(iferror(vlookup(A2:A,unique(sort(sheet2!A2:B,1,1,2,0)),2,0),"In-Stock"),1,"Issued"),0,"In-Stock"),)})
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it's working nearly but I need to update it. I have added new data in sheet1 Row7 which is not present in sheet2, in this scenario I'm getting blank data with the solution you provided however I need to update that with status In-Stock. Please check the sheet

Comment: No problem - I've edited the solution. Basically, use the `iferror` value `"In-Stock'`.

Comment: Thank You, it's working fine in demo sheet, will apply this in main data if any change is needed will reach you again!

Comment: I have a doubt, will sequence matter in this solution? it's considering last entry for individual record to update final status in sheet1. I made status 0 of last entry in sheet2 for 1230E and 2nd last entry status is 1. Final status in sheet1 should be issued but instead it's in-stock. Please check sheet once, I highlighted rows in both sheets. If sequence matters it's fine if not then please rectify the solution

Comment: The solution gets ONE value for each item in Column 'C1' based on the item being furthest down the list, so with 1230E, it takes the status of 0. I'll add some help notes, but if you can explain the requirements, then I'll be in a better position to amend the solution.

Comment: it's working perfectly as expected. In sheet1 data is unique and in sheet2 multiple entries are available for same data. what will happen if we make same entry twice with status 1 in sheet2, count will vary from sheet1. Can you provide solution to restrict duplicate entry in status column with value 1. In sheet2 I added 1230E twice with value 1 in status column, here count of issued is vary from sheet1

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow - you have '1230E' in sheet2 four times (three highlighted in red).  What outcome do you need? You keep changing the requirements, so why don't you post a new problem?